# Calculating the directional derivative of the natural logarithm of Euclidean distance

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I'm trying to find the directional derivative of $$f (x,y) = \ln\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$ at $(3,-4)$ in the direction of vector normal $(-\frac{3}{5},\frac{4}{5})$.

---

By definition, the directional derivative of $f(x,y) $ at $(x_0,y_0)$ in the direction of $v$ is

$$D_vf(x_0,y_0):=\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{f(x_0+tv_x,y_0+tv_y)-f(x_0,y_0)}{t}$$

This is what I've got:

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \vec{v}} = \lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\ln\sqrt{(3-\frac{3t}{5})^2+(\frac{4t}{5}-4)^2}-\ln\sqrt{9+16}}{t}
=
\lim_{t\to0^+} \frac{\ln\sqrt{9-\frac{18t}{5}+\frac{9t^2}{25}+\frac{15t^2}{25}-\frac{32t}{5}+16)}-\ln\sqrt{25}}{t}
=
\lim_{t\to0^+} \frac{\ln{(t-5)^2}-\ln{5^2}}{2t}
=
\lim_{t\to0^+} \frac{\ln{(t-5)}-\ln{5}}{t}
$$
I'm not sure if the next step should be applying L'Hospital's rule?

$$
\lim_{t\to0^+} \frac{\ln{(t-5)}-\ln{5}}{t}\overset{\frac?0}=\lim_{t\to0^+} \frac{1}{t-5}=-\frac{1}{5}
$$
Thanks!

Comment: Your function is differentiable at $(3,-4)$ (in fact, it is diff at ${\Bbb R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$). So you can compute de the directional derivative by $D_{\vec u}f(3,-4)=\nabla f(3,-4)\cdot \frac{\vec u}{\|\vec u\|}$.

Comment: Note that $\ln(t-5)^2=2\ln(5-t)$ since $t\approx 0$

Comment: $\ln{(t-5)}$ is not defined as $t \to 0.$ Use $\ln{(t-5)^2} = \ln{(5-t)^2}$ instead.